# Proving linear independence of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Prove or disprove the following statement:

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear transformation with $n \ge 3, m \ge 3$.

If $\{\textbf{v}_1, \textbf{v}_2, \textbf{v}_3\}$ is linearly independent, then $\{T(\textbf{v}_1), T(\textbf{v}_2), T(\textbf{v}_3)\}$ is linearly independent.

Now, I realize this is a false statement, but I tried to prove it and I can't find something wrong with my proof:

To Prove: Assume $\{\textbf{v}_1, \textbf{v}_2, \textbf{v}_3\}$ is linearly independent, then $\{T(\textbf{v}_1), T(\textbf{v}_2), T(\textbf{v}_3)\}$ is linearly independent.

Proof.

Since $\{\textbf{v}_1, \textbf{v}_2, \textbf{v}_3\}$ is linearly independent, we know that $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3 = 0$ only have the trivial solution (from the definition of linear independence). Taking the linear transformation of both sides would result in $T(c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3)=T(0)$

$\Rightarrow T(c_1v_1) + T(c_2v_2) + T(c_3v_3) = 0$

$\Rightarrow c_1T(v_1) + c_2T(v_2) + c_3T(v_3) = 0$

Since we know from our assumption that $\{\textbf{v}_1, \textbf{v}_2, \textbf{v}_3\}$ is linearly independent, we know that $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are all zero.

Therefore, $\{T(\textbf{v}_1), T(\textbf{v}_2), T(\textbf{v}_3)\}$ is linearly independent.

Q.E.D.

One thing that kind of strikes me is that I don't take into account what the linear transformation does, so I don't take into account that it's a  $T: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ linear transformation with restrictions on $n, m$. But yeah I would  really like to know what exactly is wrong with my proof, since it leads me to the wrong conclusion. Thanks in advance!

Comment: even though the claim is false in some cases, you’re proof needs to start with the assumption that $\sum_{i=1}^3c_iT(v_i)=\vec{0}$ and the use the given that $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

You are implicitly assuming that $T$ is one-to-one when you move from $$T(c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3) = T(0) = 0$$ to $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3 = 0$. (You don't state this explicitly but it is implicit in your attempted proof). That assumption is unwarranted and is in fact false if $T$ has a non-trivial kernel.

Comment: So I'm basically only saying, well, yes, $c_1T(v_1)+c_2T(v_2)+c_3T(v_3) = 0$ holds true, but that doesn't mean that there aren't non zero constants that will also make this true, is this correct?